# ** BUILD FAILED ** ... Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm having trouble while trying to build my Ionic application, at first I thought it was something with the Ionic itself, the new version came and I don't have any problem build other applications.

Here it is what I get when I try to build

```
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **
```

The following build commands failed:

```
     Ld build/emulator/Cartão\ Reforma\ Assistência\ Técnica.app/Cartão\ Reforma\ Assistência\ Técnica normal x86_64
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,
```

Print screen with the whole error:

[image]

Comment: See this: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1641

Comment: Thanks man, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Great :) I have put it as an answer since it'll help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

> you can't use cordova-plugin-firebase and phonegap-plugin-push
>   together as will result in this error. Look at v2.0.0-rc2 release of
>   this plugin for FCM support.

You can read more about [**this here**](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1641)